# What are the words in the background of fun.'s "Some Nights"?

Tags: meaning

in the song "Some Nights" by fun., there is a part where (at least it sounds like) [multiple people start singing "come on"](https://youtu.be/qQkBeOisNM0?t=3m9s). Underneath this, there appears to be what sounds like a radio transmission from like the 60s or something. I've listened to this song so many times, and ive listened to that part on high volume (which added nothing in terms of understanding), but i still can't figure out. i've looked it up and tried a bunch of trivia sites, but can't find anything that acknowledges it.

i really like these kind of low-key inserts and/or references because they can add a lot to a song, and not being able to figure this out is driving me nuts...

so in conclusion i guess, if anyone is more observant and/or skilled than i am and has deduced the origins and/or meaning of the underpinned audio (if it does exist and im not just going insane), 'twould be greatly appreciated if you disseminate such knowledge.

i bid thee all a good day

Comment: Can you tell us when it happens in the song? A link with the time would be great, because I listened to the song and I didn't hear any 60s style radio transmission recording.

Comment: I can confirm I hear it too --I added a timestamped link.  It might begin in the first set of "come ons", but it's very quiet.  It's more audible, but not enough to distinguish words.  It sounds like a mixed gender group of people chanting in unison.  Maybe someone can isolate it digitally.

Comment: It starts at around 2:26 as far as I can tell.

Comment: Confirm I hear it too, was hoping to get answers from this network